# How to capture http request by using android app

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which will track all the http and https request of my phone and display that request as an result.

So please anyone suggest me how to do that using android app.

Comment: have you made any progress in this? show us the code then.

Comment: I don't know hot to do that by using android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny I just ran across this a couple of minutes before reading your question.  They are talking about an app that does exactly the same thing.  From the text of [this post](http://www.expertsguys.com/post/Why-does-my-flashlight-app-need-GPS-permisions.aspx) I can assume that this is no small feat.  They have taken the approach of setting up a virtual enviroment to capture all http requests.  This requires rooting your phone.  I would expect if you wanted to check a particular app you could load the app in an emulator and log the emulator's requests.

Comment: So can you provide any solution how to do that in emulator?

Comment: I was thinking of WireShark in particular. It can be set up to monitor Virtual Machines. I also found [link] this app(http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/tpacketcapture_cdjxp.html) (captures on the device to SD Card, use wireshark to see details Android 4.01+ required but no root).

Comment: Wireshark is good but i want android app to capture http/https request.